Passing dynamically generated classes' instances as parameters for celery tasks
Goal
The objective is to pass an instance of a dynamically generated class (inheriting from a statically defined one) as a parameter to a task to be executed on a Celery worker.
Issue
I am encountering an error at runtime, when trying to pass my instance as parameter: kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Can't pickle local object 'ChildClassGenerator.generate.<locals>.ChildClass'.
Minimal code to reproduce (see EDIT 1)
classes.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ParentClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1: str = "attribute1"

    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self) -> str:
        pass


class ChildClassGenerator:
    @staticmethod
    def generate(value: int) -> type[ParentClass]:
        class ChildClass(ParentClass):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.value: int = value

            def some_method(self) -> str:
                return f"{self.value} - {vars(self)}"
        return ChildClass

worker.py
from celery import Celery

from classes import ParentClass


def attach_test_task(celery_worker: Celery) -> Celery:
    @celery_worker.task(name="some_task")
    def some_task(some_instance: ParentClass) -> str:
        print(f"{some_instance.some_method()}")
        return some_instance.some_method()

    return celery_worker


def build_worker() -> Celery:
    celery_worker: Celery = Celery(
        "worker",
        broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672",
        backend="rpc://",
        result_expires=300
    )

    celery_worker.conf.task_default_queue = "worker"
    celery_worker.conf.event_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.task_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.result_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.accept_content = [
        "json", "application/json", "application/x-python-serialize"
    ]
    celery_worker.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True

    celery_worker = attach_test_task(celery_worker=celery_worker)

    return celery_worker


worker: Celery = build_worker()

main.py
from celery.canvas import Signature

from worker import worker
from classes import ChildClassGenerator, ParentClass


def main():
    some_class: type[ParentClass] = ChildClassGenerator.generate(value=1)
    some_instance: some_class = some_class()
    task_signature: Signature = worker.signature("some_task")
    task = task_signature.delay(
        some_instance=some_instance
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

To test, run celery -A worker.worker -q worker --loglevel DEBUG --concurrency=2 and python main.py with a local RabbitMQ.
Modifications
The raised error led me to this GitHub issue from 2016-2017. It seems to recommend using dill as a serializer instead of pickle when trying to serialize locally defined objects. This led to the following modifications in worker.py:
import dill
from celery import Celery
# ADDED IMPORT
from kombu.serialization import registry

from classes import ParentClass


def attach_test_task(celery_worker: Celery) -> Celery:
    @celery_worker.task(name="some_task")
    def some_task(some_instance: ParentClass) -> str:
        print(f"{some_instance.some_method()}")
        return some_instance.some_method()

    return celery_worker


# ADDED METHOD
def register_dill():
    def encode(obj):
        return dill.dumps(obj=obj)

    def decode(s):
        deserialized_object = dill.loads(str=s)
        return deserialized_object

    registry.register(
        name="dill",
        encoder=encode,
        decoder=decode,
        content_type="application/x-my-content",
        content_encoding="binary"
    )


def build_worker() -> Celery:
    celery_worker: Celery = Celery(
        "worker",
        broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672",
        backend="rpc://",
        result_expires=300
    )

    # ADDED CALL
    register_dill()

    celery_worker.conf.task_default_queue = "worker"
    celery_worker.conf.event_serializer = "dill"        # CHANGED SERIALIZER
    celery_worker.conf.task_serializer = "dill"         # CHANGED SERIALIZER
    celery_worker.conf.result_serializer = "dill"       # CHANGED SERIALIZER
    celery_worker.conf.accept_content = [
        "dill", "application/x-my-content",             # ADDED ACCEPTED CONTENT
        "json", "application/json", "application/x-python-serialize",
    ]
    celery_worker.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True

    celery_worker = attach_test_task(celery_worker=celery_worker)

    return celery_worker


worker: Celery = build_worker()


Modifications results
While this has been somewhat successful, seeing we do not have the error when running the main.py, it is now the worker which crashes following a Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("Can't pickle local object 'ChildClassGenerator.generate.<locals>.ChildClass'"). (See EDIT 2)
My questions

Is there a way to fix this for the worker to work?
If not, is there a way to achieve what I want here?

Thanks a lot!
EDIT 1
After some tests, it seems another way to trigger the error is to define a lambda and passing this as a parameter. The minimal code is then shorter:
worker.py
from celery import Celery


def attach_test_task(celery_worker: Celery) -> Celery:
    @celery_worker.task(name="some_task")
    def some_task(function: Callable = lambda x: print(x)):
        function("Hello")

    return celery_worker


def build_worker() -> Celery:
    celery_worker: Celery = Celery(
        "worker",
        broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672",
        backend="rpc://",
        result_expires=300
    )

    celery_worker.conf.task_default_queue = "worker"
    celery_worker.conf.event_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.task_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.result_serializer = "pickle"
    celery_worker.conf.accept_content = [
        "json", "application/json", "application/x-python-serialize"
    ]
    celery_worker.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True

    celery_worker = attach_test_task(worker=celery_worker)

    return celery_worker


worker: Celery = build_worker()

main.py
from celery.canvas import Signature

from worker import worker


def main():
    task_signature: Signature = worker.signature("some_task")
    task = task_signature.delay(function=lambda x: print(f"{x}{x}"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This triggers the same errors, and the modification to include dill seems to have the same effects.
EDIT 2
I first verified that dill was indeed able to dump and load <locals>.
lambda_sender.py
from typing import Callable

import dill


def main():
    function: Callable = lambda x: 2*x
    with open("testing_dill", "wb") as file:
        dill.dump(function, file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

lambda_receiver.py
import dill


def main():
    with open("testing_dill", "rb") as file:
        file_content = file.read()
    deserialized_object = dill.loads(file_content)
    print(deserialized_object(5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This results in 10 being printed out, as desired.
Then I looked more into the dill decoder, and I found something surprising. When adding a breakpoint before the decoder's return statement to explore the deserialized_object, it seems the object is decoded correctly (deserialized_object[1]["some_instance"].some_method() results in "1 - {'attribute1': 'attribute1', 'value': 1}", which is the expected/desired behavior). Thus it seems the object is correctly decoded, but the next steps are blocking the code execution.
EDIT 3
After exploring the stack trace, I've found the following. (Every method or class here is defined in celery.concurrency.asynpool, unless stated otherwise, ellipses have been added to shorten the definitions and focus on important parts)
To trigger a task, Celery seems to be registering the async pool with the current event loop (through AsynPool.register_with_event_loop(self, hub: ...)).
This in turn calls the AsynPool._create_write_handlers(self, hub: ..., ..., dumps: ... = _pickle.dumps, ...) method as such self._create_write_handlers(hub). Notice that this forces the dumps parameter to its default value of pickle.dumps.
We already know this serializer doesn't work for us. This also seems to prevent us from passing dill.dumps instead of pickle.dumps, as the register_with_event_loop doesn't offer the option to change the serializer.
Even if this was supported in this method, there is an entire stack trace of calls where this parameter would need to be added, isn't it?
EDIT 4
For completeness, I also have opened a GitHub discussion on the Celery GitHub repository.
EDIT 5
Changing the default serializer (and deserializer) has worked, I opened two PRs, on Celery and on Billiard. It seems it doesn't have any adversarial effects, though I have not been able to use the test suite.

Pickle is not designed to serialize lambdas, or instances of dynamically-generated classes. This is because serializing such objects would necessarily mean pickling the entire class, including the code used to construct it (as the code might be dynamic, e.g. generated via eval()). That would be very expensive to do, and wholly unnecessary in the vast majority of cases.
Instead, the pickle module provides a standardized way to pickle instances of custom objects via the __reduce__ magic method. In your example, you can define a __reduce__ method and a helper function which restores the state of your nested class:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ParentClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1: str = "attribute1"

    @abstractmethod
    def some_method(self) -> str:
        pass


class ChildClassGenerator:
    @staticmethod
    def generate(value: int) -> type[ParentClass]:
        class ChildClass(ParentClass):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.value: int = value

            def some_method(self) -> str:
                return f"{self.value} - {vars(self)}"

            def __reduce__(self):
                return child_class_restorer, (self.value,)

        return ChildClass


def child_class_restorer(value):
    return ChildClassGenerator.generate(value)()

import pickle
obj = ChildClassGenerator.generate(0)()
# this will use __reduce__ to pickle the object,
# and the resulting pickle will use the child_class_restorer top-level function
# to restore the object
pkl = pickle.dumps(obj)
print(pickle.loads(pkl))


I already saw this answer here. This does not solve the lambda issue, whereas the dill fix does. When it comes to classes, when not using a celery worker sharing the code, you would need to redefine every parent class in addition of the ChildClassGenerator. This is not ideal if you have long chains of inheritance. For the use with Celery, in my case, I agree this should work, though I find it would add another layer of complexity to an already very abstract part of the code, which would not be in favor of readability.
